# How to find Nash equilibrium in pure and mixed strategies? Problem.

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

A two player game.
Players choose a number from a segment $[0;1]$.
A payoff function of the first player $f_1(x,y)=|x-y|,$ 
where $x$ and $y$ - the numbers chosen by the first and the second players respectively. A payoff function of the second player $f_2(x,y)=-|x-y|.$
How to find Nash equilibrium in pure(if it exists) and mixed strategies in the game?

Comment: **Hint:** Suppose the first player plays the mixed strategy of choosing $\ x\ $ randomly from $\ \left[0, 1\right]\ $ according to a uniform distribution, and the second player chooses the pure strategy $\ y_0 \in \left[0, 1\right]\ $. What will each player's expected payoff be?

Comment: If you meant expected value of $|x-y|$, it equals $y_0^2-y_0+1/2$

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I made an arithmetic mistake in my calculations, and it doesn't help. My apologies for sending you on a wild goose chase.  At the risk of doing so again, I'll try to make up for my blunder by suggesting you try the same calculation for the first player's mixed strategy of choosing $\ 0\ $ with probability $\ \frac{1}{2}\ $ and $\ 1\ $ with probability $\ \frac{1}{2}\ $.  If  I have done my sums properly this time, your answer should be independent of $\ y_0\ $.

Comment: Did Mike Earnest write that way(below)?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly no pure strategy equilibrium exists. If player one plays $x_0$ and player two plays $y_0$, and these values are unequal, then player two would benefit by playing $x_0$. If $x_0=y_0$, then player one would benefit by playing literally anything else.

Player two wants their choice to be as close to player one's ass possible. If player two plays $1/2$ with probability $1$, then they win at least $-1/2$ no matter what. No other pure strategy guarantees this payoff.

Player one wants to be as far away as possible; they need to be unpredictable, otherwise player two beats them by playing their strategy. A sensible idea is to choose one of the extremal points $0$ or $1$ with equal probability. If player two choose $y$, then the expected score for player $1$ is $\frac12(1-y)+\frac12(y-0)=\frac12$.

Since player one can guarantee their score is at least $1/2$, and player two can guarantee it is at most $1/2$, we have found *a* Nash equilibrium of the game, and the game's value. There are others; for example, both players could randomly choose between $0$ and $1$. I am not sure what the set of all Nash equilibria is.

Comment: And how to write it more formally mathematically?